# Apply onClick functions based on conditions within components React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which renders a bunch of components called **ActionItem**

```
            <ActionItem title={'Client Assigned'} icon={<MdOutlineAssignmentTurnedIn />} />
            <ActionItem title={'Inital Client Follow Up'} icon={<BsFillPersonCheckFill />} />
            <ActionItem title={'Validated Need'} icon={<BiDonateHeart />} />

            <ActionItem title={'Initiated Discovery'} icon={<RiCompassDiscoverLine />} />
            <ActionItem title={'Service In Progress'} icon={<GiProgression />} />
            <ActionItem title={'Fulfilled The Need'} icon={<ImCheckmark />} />
```

Inside of my **ActionItem** I have a function: `handleToggle()` which fires  `onClick` and pretty much adds or removes an "active" class. I want this function available to every component EXCEPT the one with the title of 'Client Assigned'

**ActionItem component:**

```
  const [toggleItem, setToggleItem] = useState(false)
  const [date, setDate] = useState('')

  const handleToggle = () => {

    setToggleItem(!toggleItem)
    setDate(new Date())
    if (date !== '') {
      setDate('')
    }

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    title === 'Client Assigned' ? handleToggle() : null
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={toggleItem ? 'ReportsModal' : 'ReportsModal not-active'}>
        <span
          style={title === 'Fulfilled The Need' ? (
            { borderColor: 'green', backgroundColor: 'green', color: '#fff' }
          ) : null}
          className={'hover'}
          onClick={title === 'Client Assigned' ? handleToggle : null}>
          {icon}
        </span>
        <div>
          <h3>{title}</h3>
          <p>{date !== '' ? moment(date).format('D MMM YYYY') : date}</p>
          {toggleItem ? (
            <h5 onClick={handleInitComment} className='hover'><AiOutlinePlusCircle style={iconStyles} /> Add Comment</h5>
          ) : null}

        </div>
      </div>
```

the conditional I am trying to use is currently not working. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to fire handleToggle conditionally based on the title === "Client Assigned", I would do this.

```
const handleToggle = (title) => {
        if (title === "Client Assigned") {
            setToggleItem(!toggleItem)
            setDate(new Date())
            if (date !== '') {
                setDate('')
            }
        }
    }
```

then your onClick would look like:

```
onClick={(title) => handleToggle(title)}>
```

This should work and is a lot easier to read aswell

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of banned/prohibited titles and use an AND operator in the onClick prop. For example:

```
function Component({ title, handleToggle }) {
  const bannedTitles = ["Client Assigned"];

  useEffect(() => {
    title === "Client Assigned" ? handleToggle() : null;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={() => !bannedTitles.includes(title) && handleToggleItem()}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Component;
```